# How to prevent extendedchars=\true from producing a blank line?

Tags: listings

My previous question [How to suppress BOM effect in the output?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5935/2099) has been solved by @Vaulty. Enabling `extendedchars=\true`, however, produces an unnecessary blank line at the first line as shown below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset
{ 
        breaklines=true,
        tabsize=3, 
        showstringspaces=false,
        extendedchars=\true,%<======= SOURCE OF PROBLEM
        language={[Sharp]C},   
        frame=single,   
        rulecolor=\color{red}%   
}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting{Program.cs}

\end{document}
```

`Program.cs`, that is generated by Visual Studio, is always prefixed with a BOM (Byte Order Mark). If you have no Microsoft Visual Studio installed, you can download a test file  named [Default.aspx.cs](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/2/8/728F8794-E59A-4D18-9A56-7AD2DB05BD9D/MovieApp_CS.zip) from the official ASP.NET website securely.
It is worth mentioning that the backslash in `\true` is NOT a typo.

The question is how to prevent `extendedchars=\true` from producing a blank line?

Comment: @xport: are you sure about `\true`? Shouldn't it be `extendedchars=true` without the backslash?

Comment: @egreg, the backslash is needed.

Comment: and where is the sense of `\true` instead of `true`?

Comment: @Herbert: `\true` works with a blank line and `true` does not work at all. I don't know why the package author chose this convention.

Comment: I, however, know who doesn't read [documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings#section4.7).

Comment: @Herbert: `\true` might be a command with a bunch of codes.

Comment: I also know who have not tried the code :)

Comment: @Herbert, @Andrey, @egreg: I will delete this question because I forgot to include `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` as what @Vaulty said in his answer.

Comment: @xport: sorry, but `\true` makes only sense, when it is defined as `\def\true{true}`. However `extendedchars` can be used without setting it to `true`, because `true` it is the default.

Comment: @xport: package `listings` cannot handle utf8. You have to choose in such a case `listingsutf8`

Comment: @xport: You should start your question by explaining that your are talking about a `listings` listing. Also edits to add clarifications should be worked into the normal text and not simply appended. There is no need to highlight edits this way. Also note that the `@username` notification doesn't work in question and answers, just in comments and then only if the user already commented below the same post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the solution that has been actually answered by Vaulty. Unfortunately, I did not realize that `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` is needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}%<========= MANDATORY
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset
{ 
        breaklines=true,
        tabsize=3, 
        showstringspaces=false,
        extendedchars=\true,%<======= MANDATORY, it is not a typo :)
        language={[Sharp]C},   
        frame=single,   
        rulecolor=\color{red}%   
}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting{Default.aspx.cs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: again: your setting with `\true` makes no sense! Same for `utf8`

Comment: @Herbert: the above code works well. I don't get a blank line. I don't get three  strange characters as well.

Comment: @Herbert: Above code uses `utf8x`.

Comment: sure, as long as your code has no special utf8 character it works, otherwise not!

Comment: I’m sorry, I’ve decided to downvote the answer since it only works by accident. Moreover, `extendedchars=\true` is really misleading (it actually means `extendedchars=false`).

Answer (score 5):

The correct syntax is `extendedchars=true` without the backslash. But it doesn't make sense without inputenc. And with inputenc and/or fontenc+T1 you don't get the wanted result as then the input will give characters.

If you use a command as value this inserts after the BOM a new line in the code. That's why it looks as if is it a solution to your problem. But actually it will break again if you load inputenc or fontenc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\lstset
{
        breaklines=true,
        tabsize=3,
        showstringspaces=false,
        extendedchars=\blub,%<======= SOURCE OF PROBLEM
        language={[Sharp]C},
        frame=single,
        rulecolor=\color{red}%
}

\begin{document}
abc
\lstinputlisting{test-bom.txt}

\end{document}
```

And here a suggestion how to get around the BOM-problem when your main document is utf8 and the listing is (with the exception of the BOM) pure ASCII:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{listings}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

 \lstset{%
 language={[Sharp]C}}

\begin{document}

\begingroup  
 \inputencoding{ansinew}
 \lstset{
   literate={^^ef^^bb^^bf}{}0
 }
 \lstinputlisting{test-bom.txt}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code snippet produces 3 "strange" characters at the first row.

Comment: @xport Yes I know. That is what I wanted to demonstrate: The extendedchar solution works only under some conditions. It doesn't work by design but by accident. I have added a suggestion how to solve the BOM problem when the main document is ASCII and the listings contains (beside the BOM) only ASCII chars. If your listings contains non-ASCII-chars it will probably break in any case.

Comment: This  BOM issue only occurs in MikTeX, not in TeXLive.

Answer (score 2):

There is no empty line with

```
\lstset{ 
        breaklines,
        tabsize=3, 
        showstringspaces=false,
        extendedchars,
        language={[Sharp]C},   
        frame=single,   
        rulecolor=\color{red}%   
}
```

Comment: Using your setting and if you don't include `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, there will be no blank line but you will get 3 unnecessary spaces prefixing the first row.

Comment: sure, it is a character and handled by `listings`, but it was you who said, that you need `\true` and get an empty line. And as I wrote utf8 is not useful with package `listings`

Comment: Sorry. I mean `utf8x` in my above comment, not `utf8`.

Comment: @xport: that doesn't matter

Answer (score 2):

The `extendedchars` option of the `listings` package is relevant if you want to typeset source code that includes non-ASCII characters using a TeX engine without native Unicode support such as pdfTeX. Obviously, the `listings` package has to deal a lot with category codes and, specifically, the `extendedchars` option addresses collaboration with the `inputenc` package which traditionally enables non-ASCII encoding of LaTeX input files via character activation.

By current design, the collaboration of the `listings` package with the `inputenc` package is restricted to single-byte encodings such as ISO-8859-1 and ISO-8859-15.  As a consequence, the default value of the `extendedchars` option (i.e. `true`) is no use when the source code to be typeset is encoded in UTF-8, independently of whether the `utf8` or the `utf8x` module is loaded by the `inputenc` package. In either case, you get errors and faulty output.

If the `extendedchars` option is set to `false` (or `\true`, `\chapter`, `\documentclass` etc. ;-) ) the `listings` package doesn’t attempt to collaborate with the `inputenc` package. Depending on the combination of active input encoding and UTF-8 character, this may **accidentally** result in pseudo-correct output (as is the case with the combination `utf8x` + BOM). In general, however, you get errors and/or faulty output once again.

To sum up: When the source code to be typeset is encoded in UTF-8 playing around with the `extendedchars` option doesn’t make sense. But there are two other possibilities:

- Resort to the `literate` option as suggested by Ulrike Fischer.
- Instead of the `listings` package, use the `listingsutf8` package in conjunction with the extended `inputencoding` option:

  ```
  ...
  \usepackage{listingsutf8}
  \lstset{%
    inputencoding=utf8/ascii,
    breaklines=true,
    tabsize=3,
    showstringspaces=false,
    language={[Sharp]C},
    frame=single,
    rulecolor=\color{red}%
  }
  ...
  ```

  Actually, the `listingsutf8` package is only capable of handling UTF-8 characters that can be translated to some single-byte encoding. UTF-8 characters such as the BOM that can’t be translated to any single-byte encoding are silently ignored. This may or may not be desirable. In case of the BOM, it fortunately is.

Comment: Have you read my answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47816/9467?

Comment: @DamienWalters: Yes, but if you use pdfTeX and the output seems OK to you it’s just another coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

This issue only happens in MikTeX. Without using `utf8x` encoding and/or `extendedchars` option, this issue disappears if you use TeXLive.

Comment: If this is the case it’s only by accident.