# lst include has first line indented

Tags: listings, indentation, code

When I'm including a source file, by way of `\lstinputlistings{file/path/to/file}`

However, This results in the following below:

[image]

Why is the first line not being formatted correctly? And how do i fix it? I've tried adding newlines before but that has no effect.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5935/how-to-suppress-bom-effect-in-the-output

Comment: dang, that's it, thanks :) If you could post that as an answer or mark this question as a duplicate, that'd be lovely.

Answer (score 0):

Just give

```
\noindent\lstinputlisting{file/path/to/file}
```

a try. It suppresses the paragraph indentation after beginning a new line.