# Unwanted Blank Front Page in article class

Tags: blank-page

I am getting an unwanted first page in both the article and Koma-Script article classes and I can't figure out why. Here's the bare bones MWR:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{article} %scrartcl class also tried
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{geometry} This didn't work
%\geometry{letterpaper} This didn't help either
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{The Article}
\author{Author}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\Blindtext{5}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions welcomed. I tried "oneside" in case somehow there was an additional verso page added, and letterpaper was because Koma's default is A4. The results were the same: an unwanted blank page before the title and text of the article. I've used Kile, Texshop and Texworks on both Linux and Mac, same results.

I get the same result if I delete the two \geometry commands.

Here's the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./additionalpage1.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/blindtext/blindtext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty))
(./additionalpage1.aux) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/u
pdmap/pdftex.map}] [2] [3] (./additionalpage1.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/local/texlive/2013/te
xmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2013/texm
f-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb>
Output written on additionalpage1.pdf (3 pages, 28954 bytes).
SyncTeX written on additionalpage1.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on additionalpage1.log.
```

File list:

```
*File List*
article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size12.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
babel.sty    2013/05/16 v3.9f The Babel package
english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
blindtext.sty    2012/01/06 V2.0 blindtext-Package
xspace.sty    2009/10/20 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
```

---

Here is the \showoutput log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./additionalpage2.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script document class (article)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package scrlfile, 2012/06/15 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
              Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize12pt.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package typearea, 2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/blindtext/blindtext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty))
(./additionalpage2.aux)
\openout1 = `additionalpage2.aux'.

Missing character: There is no ï in font cmr12!
Missing character: There is no » in font cmr12!
Missing character: There is no ¿ in font cmr12!

Completed box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(651.22751+0.0)x465.23814
.\glue -45.89749
.\vbox(697.125+0.0)x460.72128, shifted 4.51686
..\vbox(18.125+0.0)x460.72128, glue set 18.125fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x460.72128
..\glue 21.75
..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
..\vbox(606.5+0.0)x460.72128, glue set 594.43651fil
...\write-{}
...\write1{\select@language{english}}
...\write1{\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{english}}}
...\write1{\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{english}}}
...\write1{\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{english}}}
...\glue(\topskip) 12.0
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x460.72128, glue set 448.9714fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x11.74988
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
..\glue(\baselineskip) 43.01668
..\hbox(7.73332+0.0)x460.72128
...\hbox(7.73332+0.0)x460.72128
....\vbox(7.73332+0.0)x460.72128
.....\hbox(7.73332+0.0)x460.72128, glue set 227.42317fil
......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
......\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 1
......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil

{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}

Completed box being shipped out [2]
\vbox(651.22751+0.0)x465.23814
.\glue -45.89749
.\vbox(697.125+0.0)x460.72128, shifted 4.51686
..\vbox(18.125+0.0)x460.72128, glue set 18.125fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x460.72128
..\glue 21.75
..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
..\vbox(606.5+0.0)x460.72128, glue set 446.47804fil
...\write-{}
...\glue(\topskip) 12.0
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
...\glue 23.49976
...\glue -23.49976
...\penalty -51
...\glue 23.49976
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 12.72221
...\hbox(17.27779+0.0)x460.72128, glue set 129.527fil
....\glue(\leftskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.....\glue 0.0
.....\glue 0.0
.....\glue -5.87494
.....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.....\glue 5.87494
....\penalty 0
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/24.88 T
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/24.88 h
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/24.88 e
....\glue 9.12271 plus 4.56136 minus 3.0409
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/24.88 G
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/24.88 r
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/24.88 e
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/24.88 a
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/24.88 t
....\glue 9.12271 plus 4.56136 minus 3.0409
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/24.88 A
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/24.88 r
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/24.88 t
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/24.88 i
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/24.88 c
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/24.88 l
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/24.88 e
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 5.87494
...\glue 11.74988
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 6.60007
...\hbox(15.39993+6.60007)x460.72128, glue set 199.46089fil
....\glue(\leftskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
....\hbox(15.39993+6.60007)x61.79951
.....\mathon
.....\vbox(15.39993+6.60007)x61.79951
......\hbox(15.39993+6.60007)x61.79951
.......\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
.......\hbox(15.39993+6.60007)x61.79951
........\rule(15.39993+6.60007)x0.0
........\glue 6.0
........\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
........\OT1/cmr/m/n/17.28 A
........\OT1/cmr/m/n/17.28 u
........\OT1/cmr/m/n/17.28 t
........\OT1/cmr/m/n/17.28 h
........\OT1/cmr/m/n/17.28 o
........\OT1/cmr/m/n/17.28 r
........\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
........\glue 6.0
.......\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
.....\mathoff
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 11.74988
...\glue 0.0 plus 11.74988
...\penalty -51
...\glue 13.0 plus 6.0 minus 8.0
...\glue 23.49976
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
..\glue(\baselineskip) 43.01668
..\hbox(7.73332+0.0)x460.72128
...\hbox(7.73332+0.0)x460.72128
....\vbox(7.73332+0.0)x460.72128
.....\hbox(7.73332+0.0)x460.72128, glue set 227.42317fil
......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
......\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 2
......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil

(./additionalpage2.aux)

 *File List*
scrartcl.cls    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script document class (article)
scrkbase.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent ba
sics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2012/06/15 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2012/04/04 v3.10b KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize12pt.clo    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt)
typearea.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (type area)
babel.sty    2013/05/16 v3.9f The Babel package
english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
blindtext.sty    2012/01/06 V2.0 blindtext-Package
xspace.sty    2009/10/20 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
 ***********

 )</usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb></
usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmssbx10.pfb>
Output written on additionalpage2.pdf (2 pages, 25351 bytes).
SyncTeX written on additionalpage2.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on additionalpage2.log.
```

Comment: Any errors in the `.log`? Clear all your auxiliary files and try again.

Comment: No errors in the log file. I deleted all aux files, same result (on Texshop on Mac, I haven't tried Kile on Linux).

Comment: Any hidden characters between `\begin{document}` and `\maketitle`?

Comment: One carriage return. A carriage return follows \maketitle as well.

Comment: On my current MiKTeX 2.9 everything works as wanted/expected.  Please add `\listfiles` as first command in your MWE and show us the result (list of used packages at the end of log file)

Comment: *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   babel.sty    2013/05/16 v3.9f The Babel package
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
blindtext.sty    2012/01/06 V2.0 blindtext-Package
  xspace.sty    2009/10/20 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
 ***********

Comment: Is the fact that I'm using a one year old system causing the problem? For LaTex with a standard document class and well-documented packages? That's depressing.

Comment: I deleted all blank lines, no effect on the result: the blank numbered page is stubbornly there under both the article and scrartcl classes.

Comment: @user26732: I would think that you'll probably get 2 pages when you don't use `\Blindtext{5}`, correct? If so, how about posting adding `\showoutput` to your preamble and remove `\Blindtext{5}`. Then we can see exactly how the pages are constructed and what crap may be found on them and where. Include the output in your `.log` that includes the `\showoutput` output.

Comment: When I did so (add \showoutput to the preamble, comment out \Blindtext(5) package but leave \blindtext package in) I get a two page document with the title on the second page. I have edited the question with the log file.

Comment: well, i can't reproduce the extra page, and i'm using tex live 2012.  there is a very peculiar result in the body -- `\Blindtext` outputs a bunch of text, followed by `5` on a new line.  however, the date for the `blindtext` package is the same as that reported in the question.  *but there's a difference in `babel`*: `babel 2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package`, `english 2005/03/30 v3.3o English support from the babel system`, and `babel.def 2008/07/08 v3.8m Babel common definitions` -- the last of these appears to be no longer needed with the other `babel` changes.

Comment: @barbarabeeton : I just copied the file to the Linux LaTex installation which was installed last week. I compiled the file and got the same result with the stubborn stray extra page. Using \clearpage immediately after \begin{document} didn't help.

Comment: @barbarabeeton : You may be on to something. Exchanging \babel for polyglossia and switching to LuaLaTex eliminated the phantom page. However, \babel won't load without specifying a language. \polyglossia will, but I don't know if English is the default language or not.

Comment: but with the babel issue, aux files must be removed as @Werner suggested

Comment: @doed I did remove them and got the same result. So far the only thing that worked is switching \babel to \polyglossia. Is it then possible to compile a file under a document class without using the babel package? Is there a default language and hyphenation scheme, as letter paper is the default for the basic article/book classes?

Comment: @user26732: The output resembles what is called a BOM - Byte Order Mark (those three missing characters... which aren't printed but actually cause some setting in your document). My suggestion is to copy the entire file and paste it into a simple editor that has *no encoding* (not sure what that might be on OS X) and the copy-and-paste it back into TeXshop and try again. See [searches for BOM](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=bom).

Comment: start fresh with a new file from the terminal, forget about the fancy editors

Comment: @Werner oops I just opened up the comment list and saw you'd already answered  in the hidden comments:-)

Comment: @user26732 do you have such encoding in your editor? If you do, please let me know. I'm looking forward to reproduce the problem. my vote for your question.

Comment: I am using Texshop under MacOs. Copying the file to Kile under Linux/Texlive yielded the same result. As far as I know, both editors support multiple encodings, but I don't see a way to display the encoding in either. I'll try opening it up in Emacs, Vim or some other (supposedly) plain-text editor to see what happens.

Comment: @user26732 , in your case, i don't believe it's the bom conspiracy, specially after you tried two editors, and neither I'd subscribe to the idea that fontenc with t1 encoding must be accompanied by babel either. Besides, you are not using windows. But again, I can be wrong, and everything will be alright.

Comment: I added \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} and the phantom page disappeared under pdflatex (using Babel and not polyglossia). The suggestion came from the BOM thread: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5935/how-to-suppress-bom-effect-in-the-output/5952#5952. Bizarre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the log you post shows

```
Missing character: There is no ï in font cmr12!
Missing character: There is no » in font cmr12!
Missing character: There is no ¿ in font cmr12!
```

which means you have a "UTF-8 BOM" at the start of the file. It is best if you can configure your editor not to do that, but if that isn't convenient there are some workarounds here:

[How to suppress BOM effect in the output?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5935/how-to-suppress-bom-effect-in-the-output/5952#5952)

Comment: Adding \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} solved the problem. Even though I've configured Texshop under MacOs to use utf8 encoding as a default, it doesn't always do so. The "Missing character" error surprised me. "¿" isn't used in English and was not present in the document. The "î" might be, but not that Spanish punctuation mark.

Comment: @user26732 those the characters are what you get if you interpret the UTF-8 bytes of the "byte order mark" character as three separate latin-1 characters so essentially they are just random junk through incorrect decoding