# Junk character appended to code using lstinputlisting

Tags: listings, input-encodings, code

Trying to learn LaTeX, I'm using a very simple document to see if I can import C# code using the listings package. I've installed MikTex, and made sure it's up to date, and I'm using pdfLateX.

The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{bluekeywords}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{greencomments}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{redstrings}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstloadlanguages{[Sharp]C}
\lstset{
    language=[Sharp]C,
    showspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    breaklines=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
    commentstyle=\color{greencomments},
    keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{redstrings},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting{DoDickey.cs}

\end{document}
```

My problem is that when I import the C# code, some junk characters are appended at the beginning.

[image: Junk Characters]

Tried a bunch of different code files, tried using \lstinputlisting[[Sharp]C]{DoDickey.cs}.

This just results in the error "Package Listings Error: File `C(.tex)' not found."

I'm assuming it's an encoding issue, but I honestly have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: that is a BOM character that is in your C#  file.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Maybe it could help, if you add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` into your preamble.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5935/how-to-suppress-bom-effect-in-the-output

Comment: @Jan byte order mark (it's a long story:-)

Comment: Looked up BOM and how to fix it in LaTeX. Another source on here suggested adding `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` (I tried simply using utf8, didn't work).

That, along with adding `extendedchars=\true` to my lstset seemed to fix the issues.

Comment: Might be a duplicate. Was not aware of the term "BOM" before writing this question.